# Ajax success always runs else in if statement

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using Ajax to login a user into the system.
Ajax success will always run the else statement even if the server returns true Boolean.
In case the login credentials were valid the else statement would run and login failed will show up, but if I refresh the page the user will be logged in.

Basically the `if(response)` never gets ran even though it is `true`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#loginButtonIdHead').click(function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'localhost/landing/login',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                email: $('#defaultForm-email1').val(),
                password: $('#defaultForm-pass1').val()
            },
            success:function(response) {
                if(response){
                    $('#messageId').text("Login Successful");
                } else {
                    $('#messageId').text("Login Failed");
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: No idea, but please fix the formatting on your code as it is very hard to follow

Comment: Could you please tell us what is the HTTP status and the body of the server response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$.ajax()` method uses anonymous functions for the success and error callbacks. This version is easier to write, and likely easier to maintain:

```
 $(function(){
  $('#loginButtonIdHead').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'localhost/landing/login',
          type: 'POST',
          data: 
          {
            email: $('#defaultForm-email1').val(),
            password: $('#defaultForm-pass1').val()
          }, success:function(response) {
              $('#messageId').text("Login Successful");
          },error: function () {
             $('#messageId').text("Login Failed");
          }
        });
      });
  });
```

So if the login are incorrect you should be getting **403 forbidden** status from the `login` api call and that would call the error callback.
Moreover, it's not a good approach to give errors on **200 success** status. So the backend developer must update it to the appropriate statuses.

Thanks.

Comment: Won't this display **"Login Successful"** even if the login details are incorrect?

Comment: if the login are incorrect you should be getting 403 forbidden status in from the api call and that would call the `error` callback.

Comment: *"the server returns true Boolean"* So I am assuming the server will return a `true`/`false` depending on the login validation on the server meaning no 403 status will be given as the post to `'localhost/landing/login'` is a success.

Comment: its not a good approach to give 200 status.. and return true/false, the backend developer must update it appropriate statuses.

Comment: Don't you think it would be best to explain that in your answer to make things more clear because without those changes the `success` will run no matter what boolean is returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193199/discussion-between-murtaza-hussain-and-newtojs).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used success and error instead of if & else statement, also made the API send 200 for success and 403 for failure. Everything is working wonderfully now.